# about nvidia graphics driver

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

I have installed NVidia graphics drivers for Ubuntu from the official  NVidia site. When I installed I wasn't able to get my battery back up.

I heard about an open source driver for Ubuntu 14.04 so I installed the bumblebee NVidia driver for my laptop.

When I installed that driver it was running quite nicely. It has given me the battery back up. Everything was fine but when I restarted my computer Ubuntu loads and I am not able to get any visuals.

My computer is the same, just like when I shut it down. There is nothing on the display but my system is running.

What can I do to run my computer with the bumblebee NVidia driver?

My computer is a Dell Inspiration 5558 with a 4 GB 920M nvidia graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

To get your computer running properly again reinstall the NVIDIA drivers and Optimus support.
Uninstall bumblebee and install **nvidia-prime**, it is the replacement to switch between graphics.

First uninstall every NVIDIA related software - boot the PC and when the **GRUB menu** appears :

Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee  
sudo apt-get update
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official NVIDIA drivers - boot the PC and when the **GRUB menu** appears :

Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

You can switch between intel and NVIDIA graphics with NVIDIA X Server Settings **Prime Profiles**.